# Which is the correct one? "When should we" or "When we should"?

Tags: word-order, should, when

I would like to know which of the following sentences is the correct one:
a) **When should we** use this or that?
 or 
b) **When we should** use this or that?
If both are correct, is there a different meaning?

Thank you all!
Best regards,
Jose.